# How to draw a horizontal line using UIView and autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Here is the code I have...this is kind of a simple question...perhaps I shouldn't do it with UIView...but I just wanna draw a decorative horizontal line to separate content.  What I am getting is no error the line just does not draw.  If I init it with a frame and turn off autolayout, then I do see the line but that's not how I want to implement it since everything is autolayout.

Below the viewDidLoad calls the other methods to create the UI elements and add the constraints.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add main layout
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.profileInfoContainer];

    // Add UI elements
    [self.profileInfoContainer addSubview:self.email];
    [self.profileInfoContainer addSubview:self.userName];
    [self.profileInfoContainer addSubview:self.hLineSeperator];
    [self.profileInfoContainer addSubview:self.navigationContainer];

    // Add Constraints
    [self addInfoContainerConst];

}
```

Below i add the constraints for all ui elements in the profileInfoContainer, including the hLineSeperator

```
- (void)addInfoContainerConst {

        // Add constrains
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_userName, _email, _hLineSeperator, _navigationContainer);
        NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                                  @"vTop":@60,
                                  @"vBttm":@5,
                                  @"hLeft":@25,
                                  @"hRight":@25,
                                  @"vMiddle":@5
                                  };

        NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-vTop-[_userName]-vMiddle-[_email]-vMiddle-[_hLineSeperator]-vMiddle-[_navigationContainer]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewsDictionary];

        NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hLeft-[_userName]-hRight-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewsDictionary];

        NSArray *constraint_POS_H_1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hLeft-[_email]-hRight-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewsDictionary];

        NSArray *constraint_POS_H_2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_hLineSeperator(1)]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewsDictionary];

        NSArray *constraint_POS_H_3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_navigationContainer]|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:metrics
                                                                                views:viewsDictionary];

        [self.profileInfoContainer addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
        [self.profileInfoContainer addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];
        [self.profileInfoContainer addConstraints:constraint_POS_H_1];
        [self.profileInfoContainer addConstraints:constraint_POS_H_2];
        [self.profileInfoContainer addConstraints:constraint_POS_H_3];
    }
```

Below is the method to create the UIView that is used to draw the line

```
    - (UIView*)hLineSeperator {
        if (!_hLineSeperator) {
            _hLineSeperator = [UIView new];
            _hLineSeperator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            _hLineSeperator.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }
        return _hLineSeperator;
    }
```

Comment: The line is probably there, somewhere.  I don't seen any code involving setting the hLiveSeperator's frame, try setting the frame is layoutSubviews?

Comment: To my knowledge, if i set the frame, then i am no longer using autolayout.  Perhaps i am wrong on that assumption.  With constraints and autolayout frames are not used.

Comment: Found my mistake, just like i thought it was a small oversight...instead of "H:|[_hLineSeperator(1)]|" i need to give it a height of 1 on the vertical side "V:|-vTop-[_userName]-vMiddle-[_email]-vMiddle-[_hLineSeperator(1)]-vMiddle-[_navigationContainer]|".  Anyway, i'll leave it up in case its help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to add constraints to subviews (specifically like the ones you want to create) created in code. You can do it something like,

```
UIView *horizontalSeperatorViewOnTop = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.(yourView).frame.size.width, 0.5f)];
horizontalSeperatorViewTop.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.(yourView) addSubview: horizontalSeperatorViewOnTop];
```

I do this in my code all the time for horizontal or vertical separators and it works great!

Comment: Sure, this works great when you are using frames but not with auto layout.